# Synonym [service-fabric] and [azure-service-fabric]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Ran across a question today tagged [service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-fabric). The excerpt is what caught my attention

> See [azure-service-fabric]

Ok... so we go look at [azure-service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-service-fabric)

> Azure Service Fabric is a distributed systems platform used to build scalable, reliable, and easily-managed applications for the cloud. Service Fabric addresses the challenges in developing and managing cloud applications. By using Service Fabric developers and administrators can avoid solving complex infrastructure problems and focus instead on implementing mission critical, demanding workloads knowing that they are scalable, reliable, and manageable.

Small facepalm for having what looks like a copied block of content (probably needs updating).

At any rate, these clearly seem to be the same thing (searching "service fabric" returns [this Azure page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/) first), and people seem to use them interchangeably. I would say [azure-service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-service-fabric) needs to be the master tag here.

Comment: While it's possible to run Service Fabric on-premise, afaik Service Fabric and Azure Service Fabric refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the list of 160 questions that were tagged [service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-fabric). Looks like they all were about the Azure Service Fabric. I added [service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-fabric) as a synonym for [azure-service-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-service-fabric).

For the concern raised in the comments about on premise systems, there is a tag [service-fabric-on-premises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-fabric-on-premises) which consists of questions related to the on premise systems, which seems to be being used quite consistently.